# Gettin Edit Value from index.jsp

Tags: java, servlets

I am newbie in `HTML` and `Servlets`. I have such a idex.jsp contents:

```
<form action="createCSV" method="get">
    <input type="text" value="D:/">
    <input type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

And I want to use value of `<input type="text" value="D:/">` inside of method Get in my `Servlet`:

```
protected void doGet( javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response )
            throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException{}
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 2):

change the input field in your html form like this:

```
<input type="text" name="userInput" value="D:/">
```

inside the servlet do that:

```
 String userInput = request.getParameter("userInput");
```

Comment: It is always good to check whether the returned value is not null. Otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException if the value was not provided.

Comment: of course but it was not part of that question. And currently I see no reason for null check becouse its doGet method is empty :)